# Can I disable the Ctrl+scroll zoom function in NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, scroll, zooming, ctrl

Is there a way to disable the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+scroll text zoom feature in NetBeans? (7.1 on Mac OS X 10.7)

There was a plugin to kill the analogue "feature" in PHPStorm but I haven't found anything for NetBeans.

Comment: In NetBeans 8.1 it is <ALT> + <SCROLL>, and most annoying <MOUSE-WHEEL-CLICK> + <SCROLL>. Anyway, same problem and same solution. Thank you for the question.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes there is. Follow these steps:

- Go to the Keymap tab in the Options window (menu "Netbeans" item "Preferences…")
- Sort the Actions column by name and look for 'Zoom Text In' and 'Zoom Text Out'
- Click on the button with the ellipsis symbol in the shortcut column and choose 'Clear' for both actions
- Click OK

Comment: Flawless victory... Thanks mate!

Comment: Keymap is now under Tools -> Options (at least on my version)

Answer (score 7):

#### NetBeans 7.3 - Windows

1. **Tools > Options**

   [image: Tools Options]
2. **Keymap** > in the "**Search:**" input box type "**Zoom Text**" > for both lines click on the ellipsis (**`...`**) > **Clear** > **OK**

   [image: Clear shortcut]